# .htaccess works locally but not on server

Tags: php, apache

I have apache & PHP on my local windows machine and my .htaccess rules work fine.  I uploaded all my files to my Linux server and get different results.  I have complete control of my Linux VPS.  It isn't shared hosting or anything.
I created a file showme.php that all requests should go to.  showme.php just outputs some $_SERVER variables just so I know it worked.  But every request to the server gives me the 404 not found.  The same request locally serves up showme.php like it should.

-Local example: [http://localhost/somepage](http://localdomain.com/somepage) (I get the correct page rendered by showme.php)

-Server example: http://mydomain.com/somepage  (I get a 404 message)

Here is my .htaccess file.  I can't figure out why I get different results.  Something with file permissions?

```
# AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
# AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . showme.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /page-unavailable/

<files ~ "\.tpl$">
order deny,allow
allow from none
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled on that server?

Comment: FYI, I have already checked and mod_rewrite is enabled when I check with phpinfo();

Comment: You might not have allow overrides enabled - Check the apache error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that in my httpd.conf I needed AllowOverride All set in one certain place. It was there in certain directories but I guess not as default..

Answer (score 0):

If you use `phpinfo()` and do a search for `mod_rewrite` (usually under configuration) you will be able to tell if you have the ability to use `RewriteRules`. This is usually why you see `IfModule` wrapped around your rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . showme.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The answer was that in my httpd.conf I needed AllowOverride All set in one certain place.  It was there in certain directories but I guess not as default.